# Запись значения привязки WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Привязал к ViewModel `TextBox`. Запускаю. Печатаю в него текст, нажимаю кнопку "Сохранить", ну или другую. И текст который я вводил не сохраняется. Поставил контрольную точку на событие, когда в модель отправляются данные. До тех пор пока курсор моргает в `TextBox`, данные в VM не отправляются, даже если я нажимаю другие кнопки на форме. Нужно щелкнуть в другое поле `TextBox`, что бы данные передались.

```
<TextBox  Height="110"  Text="{Binding Comment, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Как заставить его передавать данные, когда я нажал на кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте установить у Binding

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

Данные в VM будут обновляться сразу, не дожидаясь потери фокуса.

Comment: Вот видел же где-то.... Спасибо

Comment: @MaximK: Пожалуйста, рад, что помогло!

Comment: подскажи еще:  вот я создал класс `public class SomeClass` и в нем одна функция возвращающая значение `public string SomeFunction`. Теперь для вызова функции мне нужно делать  `(new SomeClass()).SomeFunction()`. А как сделать , что бы не вызывать  `new`? т.е. просто `SomeClass.SomeFunction()`

Comment: @MaximK: Сделать функцию статической?

Comment: То что нужно... Спасибо

Comment: @MaximK: Пожалуйста!